# 2nd LEFT OUTER JOIN not returning rows in result set even though join condition has a match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am troubleshooting a SQL `SELECT` statement in a SSIS package and cannot figure out why a 2nd left outer join is not working. Both tables that are joined have rows with an `ORIGINAL_ACCOUNT` that matches an `ORIGINAL_ACCOUNT` in the `CHARGE_OFF` table but, when I run the query it only returns the results where the `ORIGINAL_ACCOUNT` matches in the first left outer join.

I know that I could change this to use a union but, I'd like to understand why it does not work the way that it is.

```
SELECT 
    1 as COMPANY,
    'COLL1' as OPERATIONS_AREA,
    CONVERT(bigint, ISNULL(IC.number, BC.number)) AS CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
    CONVERT(bigint, CO.NUMBER) AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    ISNULL(IC.relationshipType, BC.relationshipType) AS RELATIONSHIP_TYPE ,
    '2019-07-27' AS START_DATE 
FROM 
    CHARGEOFF CO
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    IND_CUSTOMER IC ON IC.ORIGINAL_ACCOUNT = CO.ORIGINAL_ACCOUNT
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    BUS_CUSTOMER BC ON BC.ORIGINAL_ACCOUNT = CO.ORIGINAL_ACCOUNT
```

Comment: That's weird. The second outer join should not place any restriction on the returned rows.

Comment: I had the same issue in Oracle as well ..keeping the first LEFT join was giving me expected results while the 2nd left join was restricting the results and did not know it happens in T-SQL as well.. I just made sure to give Isnull conditions on the join ..I know that is not ideal but that's how I got away with the issue

Comment: Add `IC.relationshipType` and `BC.relationshipType` to the `select` list (with suitable aliases). You may find that the results make sense, i,e. the `IC` value always wins in `IsNull` over a `BC` value. Otherwise add DDL and sample data to make the problem reproducible.